# Using the material-ui-phone-number package does not show the drop down arrow for the country flag

Tags: material-ui

I am using https://github.com/alexplumb/material-ui-phone-number that is Material UI version of 'react-phone-input-2'. However it refuses to show the drop down arrow for the country flag. Below is the codesandbox that depicts that

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-herschel-c4rru?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: how did you fix this